# how to avoid missing rows? and strange case of Distinct not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

a very simple SQL statement is returning two rows instead of the one i would expect.

```
select distinct(F_NAME) from tab2 where F_NAME like '%SMITH%'

F_NAME
CLAIRE_SMITH
CLAIRE_SMITH
```

The text is the same, tried lowercase, trim and some other text functions to see if i can find a difference, but no joy. I've also re-entered the data by hand and by using an update function. I've also checked character encoding to make sure nothing weird was happening, both are `varchar(90)` and `latin1_general_ci`

The name actually exists in two tables I am looking at with around 5 rows in the `tab1` table and 100 row in `tab2`

The problem came to light when joining^1 `tab1` and `tab2` tables together where `F_NAME=F_NAME` and CLAIRE_SMITH didn't appear in the results, yet every other person in `tab1`and `tab2` are returned.

^1 right join, implicit join, left join, right join, left outer join and right outer join.

```
tab1

F_NAME, F_DEPTNO, F_AGE
CLAIRE_SMITH, 1, 17
BOB_JONES, 2, 37,
SUE_JENKINS, 2, 29,


tab2

F_ID, F_NAME, F_VALUE1, F_VALUE2, F_VALUE3
1, CLAIRE_SMITH, 10, 11, 15
2, BOB_JONES, 15, 11, 15
3, SUE_JENKINS, 20, 13, 14
4, CLAIRE_SMITH, 10, 11, 15
5, BOB_JONES, 15, 11, 15
6, SUE_JENKINS, 20, 13, 14
```

what i am trying to do is sum the values in `tab2` and group by `F_NAME`, whilst adding in some values from `tab1`, unfortunately their is no foreign key in `tab2` that i can use to aid the join and the data is provided as is and all i have to work with.

my query outputs correctly for all people except CLAIRE_SMITH who does not appear.

```
SELECT a.F_DEPTNO, a.F_NAME, sum(b.F_VALUE1), sum(b.F_VALUE2), sum(b.F_VALUE3)
FROM TAB1 a, TAB2 b WHERE a.F_NAME=b.F_NAME
GROUP BY a.F_ID, a.F_NAME 
ORDER BY a.F_ID ASC
```

can anyone explain what might be happening?
1) the name appears to be the same but is returned as two distinct instances
2) the join excludes this person.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select hex(F_NAME) from tab2 where F_NAME like '%SMITH%'
```

in order to find the difference.

[hex function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) returns a hexadecimal string representation, so any invisible (i.e space) as a string becomes revealed.

Comment: nice. yes i was able to see 5 records for Smith had a different hex value - no idea how this happened. targeting these i was able to resolve my problem. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

My reputation is too low to comment. This query might be interesting:

```
select id1.f_name=id4.f_name
from ( select f_name from tab2 where id=1 ) id1
join ( select f_name from tab2 where id=4 ) id4 using (f_name)
```

This would indicate whether the db considers those two values equal (query will return 1) or not (query will return 0)

Comment: in the example code above (in the question) this would work - either matching or not, but not a feasible answer for 100s of rows etc. the answer accepted was the quickest and easiest way to determine if the values were identical or not. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT is not a function.

That aside, I cannot reproduce this problem. Perhaps there's something you've neglected to mention...

```
CREATE TABLE tab2
( F_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, F_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, F_VALUE1 INT NOT NULL
, F_VALUE2 INT NOT NULL
, F_VALUE3 INT NOT NULL
);

 INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES
(1, 'CLAIRE_SMITH', 10, 11, 15),
(2, 'BOB_JONES', 15, 11, 15),
(3, 'SUE_JENKINS', 20, 13, 14),
(4, 'CLAIRE_SMITH', 10, 11, 15),
(5, 'BOB_JONES', 15, 11, 15),
(6, 'SUE_JENKINS', 20, 13, 14);

SELECT DISTINCT f_name FROM tab2 WHERE f_name LIKE '%smith%';
+--------------+
| f_name       |
+--------------+
| CLAIRE_SMITH |
+--------------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3b27/1

Comment: don't recall saying distinct was a function, but thanks for the sqlfiddle - i knew there was a jsfiddle, but didn't know sqlfiddle existed! this will come in very handy. thanks

Comment: You enclosed it in parentheses - which means you thought it was!